# Multiple sort of an object

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to sort a vector of objects but not like a normal sort because I need it to be sorted first with the first paramater, then with the second then with the third, etc.

Exemple:

`RandomObject.h:`

```
class RandomObject
{
public:
    RandomObject(int firstParamater, int secondParameter, int thirdParameter);
    int firstParameter();
    int secondParameter();
    int thirdParameter();
    ~ContainerFrame();
private:
    int m_firstParameter; //These aren't constant
    int m_secondParameter;
    int m_thirdParameter;
};
```

`RandomObject.cpp:`

```
ContainerFrame::ContainerFrame(int firstParamater, int secondParameter, int thirdParameter) : m_firstParameter(firstParamater), m_secondParameter(secondParameter), m_thirdParameter(thirdParameter)
{

}

ContainerFrame::~ContainerFrame()
{

}

[...function that just return members int...]
```

And now I want to sort them by the first argument, then by the second, then by the third like that:

```
RandomObject(1,1,1);
RandomObject(1,3,1);
RandomObject(2,1,5);
RandomObject(2,2,1);
RandomObject(3,1,1);
[...]
```

I know that to sort a vector you need to do a:

```
sort (randomObjectV.begin(), randomObjectV.end(), sortFunc);
```

And that sortFunc should be like that:

```
bool sortFunc(const RandomObject& firstObject, const RandomObject& secondObject);
```

But I don't know how to make a procedural sort like that.

Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: No, I want to know how to do like a procedural sort, this was only an exemple.

Comment: So you compare the first parameter first, if they are different you are done, otherwise compare the next parameter, etc.

Comment: So may be you should define the term _procedural sort_ better. It's not common tech lingo.

Comment: @Bo Persson Ok, I'm shocked I hadn't think about this when I've written down this post.

Comment: If you were using a `tuple<int,int,int>` you wouldn't even need to write anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight misconception in how sort works:

```
sort (randomObjectV.begin(), randomObjectV.end(), comparisonFunction);
```

The `comparisonFunction` compares two objects of the same type and decides which is the smaller. It returns true if the first parameter is `Less` than the second parameter (for some definition of `Less`).

So all you have to is decide how to compare two objects.

```
bool comparisonFunction(const RandomObject& firstObject, const RandomObject& secondObject)
{
    // Here is an example how how you can compare.
    return firstObject.firstParameter() < secondObject.firstParameter();
}
```

Note: because the parameters are `const` in the above function you can only call const versions function on your object. Currently you don'y have any. But I believe all your getters are const so I bet you could just add `const` to them to make them work.

```
class RandomObject
{
public:
    int firstParameter()   const; // <- Add const here
```

But alternatively. Rather than provide a comparison method to sort you can use the default comparison method. This basically uses `operator<` on your object to compare two objects. You just need to provide a defineition of `operator<` for your class.

```
    sort (randomObjectV.begin(), randomObjectV.end());

    // This will use `operator<` on your object.

    class RandomObject
    {
        public:
             bool operator<(RandomObject const& rhs) const {

                 // Again just an example of how you can implement less.
                 // The current object is the lhs.
                 return m_firstParameter < rhs. m_firstParameter;
             }
```

IT has been suggested that you what you want to learn is how to compare two objects. That is totally up to you (only you know how to compare your object).

But a common technique is the following.

```
if (lhs.m_firstParameter < rhs.m_firstParameter) return true;
if (lhs.m_firstParameter > rhs.m_firstParameter) return false;

// Otherwise the m_firstParameter is equal (so you compare the second)
if (lhs.m_secondParameter < rhs.m_secondParameter) return true;
if (lhs.m_secondParameter > rhs.m_secondParameter) return false;

// Otherwise the m_firstParameter and m_secondParameter are equal (so you compare the third)
if (lhs.m_thirdParameter < rhs.m_thirdParameter) return true;
if (lhs.m_thirdParameter > rhs.m_thirdParameter) return false;

// Otherwise all three are equal
return false
```

This is commonly shortened too:

```
return lhs.m_firstParameter < rhs.m_firstParameter ||
       (lhs.m_firstParameter == rhs.m_firstParameter && lhs.m_secondParameter < rhs.m_secondParameter) ||
       (lhs.m_firstParameter == rhs.m_firstParameter && lhs.m_secondParameter == rhs.m_secondParameter  && lhs.m_thirdParameter < rhs.m_thirdParameter);
```

But it is easier to write as:

```
return std::make_tuple(lhs.m_firstParameter, lhs.m_secondParameter, lhs.m_thirdParameter) 
     < std::make_tuple(rhs.m_firstParameter, rhs.m_secondParameter, rhs.m_thirdParameter);
```

But more efficient to write as (but has the same meaning)

```
return std::forward_as_tuple(lhs.m_firstParameter, lhs.m_secondParameter, lhs.m_thirdParameter) 
     < std::forward_as_tuple(rhs.m_firstParameter, rhs.m_secondParameter, rhs.m_thirdParameter);
```

This works because the `std::tuple` has a predefined `operator<` that does exactly what is described above (also its been reviewed as correct and efficient). So this should be your default way of comparing objects.

Comment: I don't see that he has the misconception that you're explaining.  He's asking how to implement the comparison Function so that it compares multiple members.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I disagree. It looks like he is under the imprssion he needs to write a type specific sort (like you would in C). That's why he called it a `sortFunc`. But just to cover all the basis I have added how to write a simple comparison to the end.

Comment: I already knew the part until the shortened one, I know that to compare an object you need to say what you want to compare to. But it helps me a lots thank you!

Comment: @LokiAstari: I maintain my position. look at the signatures: `sortFunc` is the name of his comparitor object, not the sorting function. But your answer now explains both parts, so that's awesome. +1.